# Create calculated column with Pandas using window and hierarchy logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the below example, how can I create the calculated column "parent_node"?

```
import pandas as pd

#create dataframe with just node column
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "node": [
        "N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13", "N07", "N07 S28", "N07 S28 G N06 S16",
        "N08 N05", "N07 S28 G N05", "N08 N05 G N27", "N07 S28 G N05 N03",
        "N07 S28 G N05 N03 G S31", "N07 S28 G N06 S16 G S32"
    ]
})

#create column called count_of_spaces_in_node
def countSpaces(cell):
    try:
        return cell.count(" ")
    except:
        return 0
df["count_of_spaces_in_node"] = df["node"].apply(countSpaces)

#sort by count_of_spaces_in_node, then by node
df = df.sort_values(by=["count_of_spaces_in_node", "node"])

#reset index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#create column called length_of_node
df['length_of_node'] = df['node'].str.len()
```

The resulting df looks like this:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 | 0 | 3 |
| N07 S28 | 1 | 7 |
| N08 N05 | 1 | 7 |
| N07 S28 G N05 | 3 | 13 |
| N08 N05 G N27 | 3 | 13 |
| N07 S28 G N05 N03 | 4 | 17 |
| N07 S28 G N06 S16 | 4 | 17 |
| N07 S28 G N05 N03 G S31 | 6 | 23 |
| N07 S28 G N06 S16 G S32 | 6 | 23 |
| N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13 | 6 | 23 |

The new calculated column called "parent_node" would look like this:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node | parent_node |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N07 | 0 | 3 |  |
| N07 S28 | 1 | 7 | N07 |
| N08 N05 | 1 | 7 |  |
| N07 S28 G N05 | 3 | 13 | N07 S28 |
| N08 N05 G N27 | 3 | 13 |  |
| N07 S28 G N05 N03 | 4 | 17 | N07 S28 G N05 |
| N07 S28 G N06 S16 | 4 | 17 | N07 S28 |
| N07 S28 G N05 N03 G S31 | 6 | 23 | N07 S28 G N05 N03 |
| N07 S28 G N06 S16 G S32 | 6 | 23 | N07 S28 |
| N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13 | 6 | 23 | N07 |

Here is the logic for creating the parent_node column, using the last row as an example:

1. Look at the count_of_spaces_in_node values for the row we're considering:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13 | 6 | 23 |

The value is 6. Now look at this hierarchy:

```
hierarchy_distinct_count_of_spaces_in_node = df.count_of_spaces_in_node.unique()
#result: array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int64)
```

2. Go up one in the hierarchy from 6 to 4. Now look at a window of the table where count_of_spaces_in_node equals 4:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 S28 G N05 N03 | 4 | 17 |
| N07 S28 G N06 S16 | 4 | 17 |

For each row in this window, consider the node and the length_of_node. Compare the node to the left length_of_node-number-of-characters of the original node. (e.g. does `N07 S28 G N05 N03` = `N07 S40 G S06 S29`? no) If there is a match, this node becomes the value for the parent_node column.

3. If, after going through all the rows in the 4-window and not getting any matches, move up the hierarchy from 4 to 3. Now repeat step 2, but using 3 for the window, like this:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 S28 G N05 | 3 | 13 |
| N08 N05 G N27 | 3 | 13 |

For each row in this window, consider the node and the length_of_node. Compare the node to the left length_of_node-number-of-characters of the original node. (e.g. does `N07 S28 G N05` = `N07 S40 G S06`? no) If there is a match, this node becomes the value for the parent_node column.

4. If, after going through all the rows in the 3-window and not getting any matches, move up the hierarchy from 3 to 1. Now repeat step 2, but using 1 for the window, like this:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 S28 | 1 | 7 |
| N08 N05 | 1 | 7 |

For each row in this window, consider the node and the length_of_node. Compare the node to the left length_of_node-number-of-characters of the original node. (e.g. does `N07 S28` = `N07 S40`? no) If there is a match, this node becomes the value for the parent_node column.

5. If, after going through all the rows in the 1-window and not getting any matches, move up the hierarchy from 1 to 0. Now repeat step 2, but using 0 for the window, like this:

| node | count_of_spaces_in_node | length_of_node |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N07 | 0 | 3 |

For each row in this window, consider the node and the length_of_node. Compare the node to the left length_of_node-number-of-characters of the original node. (e.g. does `N07` = `N07`? yes! So `N07` becomes the parent_node value.) If there had been no match, after considering this last 0-window, leave parent_node blank or NULL.

Sidenote: This may not be useful for answering the above question, but may be interesting context. I'm doing some analysis of [an opening book AI](https://github.com/simondorfman/volcanoes-game-design/blob/main/opening-book/parse_and_transform_openings.dat_to_hierarchy_of_nodes.py) for a [game design](https://simondorfman.com/volcanoes1) I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `N08 N05 G N27` will have a parent node as `N08 N05` have made the below snippet.

Try the below snippet,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "node": [
        "N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13", "N07", "N07 S28", "N07 S28 G N06 S16",
        "N08 N05", "N07 S28 G N05", "N08 N05 G N27", "N07 S28 G N05 N03",
        "N07 S28 G N05 N03 G S31", "N07 S28 G N06 S16 G S32"
    ]
})


node_list = [i.split() for i in df["node"]]

def find_par_node(x):
    
    lis = x.split(" ")
    for i in range(-1,-len(lis),-1):
        if (lis[:i] in node_list):
            return " ".join(lis[:i])
    return np.nan
    
df["parent_node"] = df["node"].apply(find_par_node)

print(df)

    node                     parent_node
N07 S40 G S06 S29 G N13      N07
N07                          NaN
N07 S28                      N07
N07 S28 G N06 S16            N07 S28
N08 N05                      NaN
N07 S28 G N05                N07 S28
N08 N05 G N27                N08 N05
N07 S28 G N05 N03            N07 S28 G N05
N07 S28 G N05 N03 G S31      N07 S28 G N05 N03
N07 S28 G N06 S16 G S32      N07 S28 G N06 S16
```